# Python Web Scraping Table

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the table of past winning numbers from `njlottery.com`.
I can see the table using 'inspect' through my browser `<table class="table table-striped cardcash-winning-numbers  table-winning-numbers">`

When I get the whole webpage using BeautifulSoup and print it out, I see the table as

```
<table class="table table-striped cardcash-winning-numbers  table-winning-numbers'+
((__t=((portalGameCode == 'PICK3' || portalGameCode == 'PICK4') ? '-pick' : ''))==null?'':__t)+
'">
```

But when I try to find the table rows using `table_body = soup.find_all('table')`, the results do not include the table I am looking for.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What is the content of your response obj. Is it empty? An error perhaps? In other words, are you getting the html response you think you are.

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems that the tables are loaded via AJAX request only after the page loaded. Using a headless browser can solve this.

Or another option is using an API provider as;
`https://rapidapi.com/scrapingbuddy-scrapingbuddy-default/api/scrapingbuddy/`

The following code shows the tables of the pic3 game:

```
import requests

url = "https://scrapingbuddy.p.rapidapi.com/v1/scrape"

querystring = {"url":"https://www.njlottery.com/en-us/drawgames/pick3.html"}

headers = {
    "X-RapidAPI-Key": "XXX",
    "X-RapidAPI-Host": "XXX"
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```